# Notation for does not converge?

Tags: notation

Is it okay to write that $x_n \not \rightarrow x$ to indicate that the sequence $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x$? Or should this notation be discouraged?

Comment: I suppose one could assign that meaning to that collection of symbols.  But why would you want to?  How often is it important what a sequence does *not* converge to?

Comment: Yes, it's very common to write $x_n \not \rightarrow x$.

Comment: It’s a fine notation, largely self-explanatory, and as @BolzWeir says, it’s not at all uncommon.

Comment: I was using this notation in a proof by contradiction where I was constructing a sequence which did not converge to a value that I was interested in. I suppose I wouldn't use this notation very often but I wanted to know if such a notation was in common use or not. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: It's much better notation than the alternative $\lim x_n\ne x$. Because the latter assumes that the limit _exists_. I see people writing $\lim x_n\ne x$ as a synonym for "it is not true that $\lim x_n=x$" and _that_ is simply _wrong_.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try to remember not to do that.